# Rails multiple resources, same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In the Rails Guide, there is this excerpt of code:

```
scope "admin" do
   resources :photos, :as => "admin_photos"
end
resources :photos
```

My question is, is there any way to distinguish between these two requests if they are routed to the same controller? For example, /photos and /admin/photos would both route to the index method of the Photos controller, but how could these requests be distinguished from one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't. Anyway you can use `namespace` method and use different controller for admin namespace (you can inherit your admin controller from photos controller if they are similar). You can find more information about `namespace` method [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaults` to distinguish it, like this:

```
scope "admin" do
   resources :photos, :as => "admin_photos", defaults: { area: 'admin' }
end
resources :photos, defaults: { area: 'public' }
```

You will have the `params[:area]` value available in your controller. You can name it differently of course.

The problem I think you may have with this is that the `form_for @photo` will always work for the ordinary `:photos` route. You have to add `form_for @photo, as: admin_photos` (which will put values into `params[:admin_photos]`), or pass the `url: admin_photos_path`.